# jQuery not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7

I'm using this jQuery to render a text box onClick.  But, It's not rendering... Also, on a side note I'm using Drupal 7.  I have the jQuery in the Head tags of the html.php.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#front-background").hide();

        $(window).load(function() {

            $('#links-top-1').hover(function() {

                $('#front-background').fadeIn(2000);

            });

        });

  });

  </script>
```

Comment: (1) I don't see any click handlers in there. (2) Why are you putting a `$(window).load()` inside a `$(document).ready()`? (3) How about some HTML to go with that JavaScript.

Comment: [Difference between $(document).ready and $(window).load in jQuery](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may also be because of how Drupal handles compatibility with other JavaScript libraries.

You can wrap your jQuery function in:

```
(function ($) {
    //your existing code
})(jQuery);
```

or if you're comfortable theming using the `template.php` file, you can add the JS through the function `drupal_add_js()`.

See http://drupal.org/node/171213 for more details.

Comment: I have a couple questions on this.  1) Is jQuery built into Drupal 7?  I'm using the API and it's not rendering. 2) I'm adding this code to the html.php.  But, It's for the page--front.tpl.php.  Is the html.php global for all template suggestions?  I'm not sure if you need to redefined html.php templates for all new template suggestions.  I recently switched to D7 so I'm not sure how I'd redefine the html.php.  Thank you.

Comment: 1) Yes, it is. You may also have to add your JS to the Drupal.behaviors object - see http://drupal.org/node/171213. 2) Yes, the html.tpl.php is the global template - the easiest way to add front-page specific logic is through an override of `yourtheme_preprocess_page` in `template.php`.

Comment: Further to 1, just adding jQuery functions through $(document).ready used to work in Drupal 6, but now 7 makes you wrap your jQuery at least in the container above.

Comment: You can also just include a JS file through the line `scripts[] = js/myscript.js` (or whatever your file's name is) in your `info` file of your theme (as long as you wrap the function, it will work and you don't have to use template files.

Comment: The problem is likely with Drupal, since your JS does work: http://jsfiddle.net/FN4Cr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `window load` event if you are already using `$(document).ready` method. Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#front-background").hide();

    $('#links-top-1').hover(function() {
       $('#front-background').fadeIn(2000);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see any onClick functionality there. This should work:

CSS:

```
#front-background {
    display:none;
}
```

JQuery hover replacement. Fade in on hover, fadeout on leave

```
$(function() {
   $('#links-top-1').hover(function() {
      $('#front-background').fadeIn(2000);
   },function(){
      $('#front-background').fadeOut(2000)
   });
});
```