# splash jquery animation page drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal, animation, frontpage

I have a nice jquery animation built on a separate page but now, would like to incorporate it as a front page in drupal. I tried panels but the jquery doesn't seem to kick in and it's hard to debug anything there. So, basically, any option is OK, including a separate static page somehow inserted into the front page, really, anything. I have to get this up soon and would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to insert a static block of HTML into a region in your front page, a good option may be the [Block Theme](http://drupal.org/project/blocktheme) module. It should work the same for Drupal 6 or 7. It can easily do what you're describing.

You can then add the jQuery for your carousel to a JavaScript file included via your theme's info file or through the theme function `drupal_add_js` ([there's more detail in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005661/jquery-not-rendering-properly/7005700#7005700)). If you're using Drupal 7 and you're including a custom JS file, you'll need to wrap your jQuery as explained in the link above.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded blocktheme and can't get it to work after checking and rechecking their readme file. Others seem to have this issue as well. At this point I am wondering about creating a new page and inserting the header from drupal, but honest, I think this is very dicey in drupal

Comment: I've pasted the page (not working on fiddle but working locally) to see if you have ideas for integrating into the drupal as a front page http://jsfiddle.net/jhanjon/hnx7t/

Comment: Well, what worked for me thus far is to get rid of all the other styles in the custom block--themeblock--custom.tpl, after all why do I need them? So this works for now:

<code>    <div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="nick"<?php print $attributes; ?>></code>
Not sure what attributes apply yet, where the default block.tpl looks like this
    <div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

At least it's a start for me to start my project.

Comment: @joe, glad that's working for you :). If my answer of going with Block Theme was helpful for you, consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Sure, not exactly sure where to do that yet, but again, this is only a start because I still need to configure all the elements and how to deal with drupal's jquery. At first I will try to not call jquery assuming it's alreayd in memory, so only the plugins and custom scripts will be called

Comment: It's working really great, in fact, I just added the style sheet using @import and left the print $classes so as to pick up the entire sheet. The style sheet indeed gets used by the block, totally! Same with the javascript, and I didn't call my version, just drupal's one which is in memory was good enough. I did use drupal_add_js and wrapped it as you suggested, thanks! When I finish and put it on a remote server, I'll post the result.